# No module named 'openslide'

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda, conda, openslide

I created a virtual environment with conda, and installed open slide.  I activated my environment, but when I try to run my Python script, I get an error saying:

```
import openslide
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'openslide'
```

I'm using python3.  Any idea what could be wrong?

I installed the package using conda. `conda env create -f environment.yml`.  File looks like

```
name: myenv
channels:
  - defaults
  - conda-forge
  - bioconda
dependencies:
  - python=3.6.3
  - openslide
```

Comment: This will be hard to answer without more information.  For a starting point, I recommend finding where you have openslide installed, and comparing that to the results of `import sys; print(sys.path)`.

Comment: did you install the package using pip?

Comment: @ScottMermelstein `['', '/cuda/libs/current/pynvml', '/home/$USER/.conda/envs/myenv/lib/python36.zip', '/home/$USER/.conda/envs/myenv/lib/python3.6', '/home/$USER/.conda/envs/myenv/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload', '/home/$USER/.conda/envs/myenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages']`

Comment: @argo, I installed the package using conda. `conda env create -f environment.yml`.

Answer (score 4):

Try this

`pip install openslide-python`

Comment: OSError: libopenslide.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory